# Concatenating lang CONST and STR CONST in PHP

Tags: php, constants, concatenation, string-concatenation

Trying to concatenate:

```
<?php
class MD_ImpFormularios extends CI_Model {
  private $dir_forms = __DIR__ . 'Hola';
```

Gives:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in md_impformularios.php on line 3
```

But I don't see anything wrong here, it isn't a CONST or Static, it's a simple variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not do concatenation while declaring class variables.

```
private $dir_forms = __DIR__ . 'Hola';
                          // ^ This is NOT allowed during declaration
```

You can use your constructor function to set such variables.

```
private $dir_forms;
public function __construct() {
    $this -> dir_forms = __DIR__ . 'Hola';
}
```

Comment: Hmmmmmmm I see, I'm looking at documentation..... the Parse Error could be better in telling you what's wrong lol.

Comment: @Jorge, It did tell you "unexpected `.`"

Answer (score 4):

You can not use conctenation when declare a class constant or variable (till php5.5, since php5.6 you can define class properties with concatenation, i find anyway better to do such tings in constructor). 
You should declare as empty string, and in constructor you can assign value to this variable.

```
    <?php
          class MD_ImpFormularios extends CI_Model {
                private $dir_forms = ''; 
                ....
                public function __construct(){
                      $this->dir_forms = __DIR__ . 'Hola'
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are concatenating a sting to set a property, which isn't allowed. You can see this example in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

```
   // invalid property declarations:
   public $var1 = 'hello ' . 'world';
```

You should set the value in the constructor instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in a class property declaration. You have to do it in the constructor:

```
<?php
class MD_ImpFormularios extends CI_Model {
  private $dir_forms;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->dir_forms = __DIR__ . 'Hola';
  }
}
```